# Can I charge my battery in another phone?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus

My phone made a weird noise yesterday when I had it on a connector to my schools computer to charge it. I plugged it in last night but it wouldn't charge. My sister has a phone of the same model. Would I be able to charge my battery in her phone? I think that the cord that I was charging with melted or something and I believe that there is not damage to the battery itself. Would it harm her phone at all if I put mine in to hers and charged it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as its the same phone and the same charger or charger port (micro usb), i don's see why anything could go wrong in charge. Try to charge it in your sister's charger and tell if it works or not.

[image: a micro usb port]

Comment: Thank you so much! We were in suspense while turning it on to make sure nothing would go wrong, and it worked perfectly! It was at 8% and I need to upload my data to the cloud and 8 wouldn't do it. Thank you!